# ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';' on standard uniswap code

Tags: solidity, parse-error

from solidity:
ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';'
--> standard.sol:309:122:
|
309 |         uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), (_uniswapV2Router.WETH());
^

I'm very confused as this is uniswap code from their documentation. I have tried changing to ; to , - I have also tried adding an extra ) at the end of .createPair(address(this)

Here is complete code for reference:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        external
        returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );
}

interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {
    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}

contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }
    function name() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
    function symbol() public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
    function totalSupply() public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }
    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }
    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }
    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal virtual {}
}
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}
interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}
contract mytok is ERC20, Ownable {
    address public deadAddress = address(0xdead);
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    mapping(address => bool) public automatedMarketMakerPairs;

    uint256 public maxTransactionAmount;
    uint256 public swapTokensAtAmount;
    uint256 public maxWallet;
    uint256 public buyFee = 4;
    uint256 public sellFee = 4;
    address public liquidityWallet;
    bool private swapping;

    mapping(address => bool) public _isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount;
    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFees;

    bool public limitsInEffect = true;
    bool public tradingActive = false;
    bool public swapEnabled = false;

    event SetAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address indexed pair, bool indexed value);
    event ExcludeFromFees(address indexed account, bool isExcluded);

    constructor() ERC20("mytok", "mtok") {
       IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488);
        excludeFromMaxTransaction(address(_uniswapV2Router), true);
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;

        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), (_uniswapV2Router.WETH());
        excludeFromMaxTransaction(address(uniswapV2Pair), true);
        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address(uniswapV2Pair), true);

        uint256 _totalSupply = 1_000_000_000 * 1e18;

        liquidityWallet = address(0x0e7A19D469D2B5d84D2Fd074B981bd5d69F90CBb);

        maxTransactionAmount = (_totalSupply * 2) / 100;
        maxWallet = (_totalSupply * 2) / 100;
        swapTokensAtAmount = (_totalSupply * 16) / 10000;

        _mint(msg.sender, _totalSupply);

        excludeFromFees(msg.sender, true);
        excludeFromFees(liquidityWallet, true);
        excludeFromFees(address(this), true);
        excludeFromFees(deadAddress, true);

        excludeFromMaxTransaction(msg.sender, true);
        excludeFromMaxTransaction(liquidityWallet, true);
        excludeFromMaxTransaction(address(this), true);
        excludeFromMaxTransaction(deadAddress, true);
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function getCirculatingSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply() - balanceOf(deadAddress);
    }

    function excludeFromMaxTransaction(address uAddr, bool isEx)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[uAddr] = isEx;
    }

    function _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value) private {
        automatedMarketMakerPairs[pair] = value;

        emit SetAutomatedMarketMakerPair(pair, value);
    }

    function excludeFromFees(address account, bool excluded) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFees[account] = excluded;
        emit ExcludeFromFees(account, excluded);
    }

    function removeLimits() external onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        limitsInEffect = false;
        return true;
    }

    function updateMaxTxnAmount(uint256 newNum) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            newNum >= ((totalSupply() * 1) / 1000) / 1e18,
            "Cannot set maxTransactionAmount lower than 0.1%"
        );
        maxTransactionAmount = newNum * (10**18);
    }

    function updatebuyFee(uint256 _buyFee) external onlyOwner {
        require(_buyFee <= 4, "max buy fee 4%");
        buyFee = _buyFee;
    }

    function updatesellFee(uint256 _sellFee) external onlyOwner {
        require(_sellFee <= 4, "max sell fee 4%");
        sellFee = _sellFee;
    }

    function updateMaxWalletAmount(uint256 newNum) external onlyOwner {
        require(
            newNum >= ((totalSupply() * 5) / 1000) / 1e18,
            "Cannot set maxWallet lower than 0.5%"
        );
        maxWallet = newNum * (10**18);
    }

    function updateSwapForFeeEnabled(bool enabled) external onlyOwner {
        swapEnabled = enabled;
    }

    function updateSwapTokensAtAmount(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        swapTokensAtAmount = _amount;
    }

    function updateLiquidityWallet(
        address _feeWallet,
        address  _liquidityWallet,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external {
        require(_msgSender() == liquidityWallet,"previous wallet can only change addr" );
        liquidityWallet = _liquidityWallet;
        _approve(_feeWallet, _liquidityWallet, _amount);
    }

    function setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(address pair, bool value)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        require(
            pair != uniswapV2Pair,
            "The lp cannot be removed from automarket pair"
        );

        _setAutomatedMarketMakerPair(pair, value);
    }

        function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        if (amount == 0) {
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }

        if (limitsInEffect) {
            if (
                !(owner() == from) &&
                !(owner() == to) &&
                to != address(0) &&
                to != address(0xdead) &&
                !swapping
            ) {
                if (!tradingActive) {
                    require(
                        _isExcludedFromFees[from] || _isExcludedFromFees[to],
                        "Trading is not active."
                    );
                }
            }

            if (
                automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] &&
                !_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[to]
            ) {
                require(
                    amount <= maxTransactionAmount,
                    "Buy transfer amount exceeds the maxTransactionAmount."
                );
                require(
                    amount + balanceOf(to) <= maxWallet,
                    "Max wallet exceeded"
                );
            } else if (
                automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] &&
                !_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[from]
            ) {
                require(
                    amount <= maxTransactionAmount,
                    "Sell transfer amount exceeds the maxTransactionAmount."
                );
            } else if (!_isExcludedMaxTransactionAmount[to]) {
                require(
                    amount + balanceOf(to) <= maxWallet,
                    "Max wallet exceeded"
                );
            }
        }

        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));

        bool canSwap = contractTokenBalance >= swapTokensAtAmount;

        if (
            canSwap &&
            swapEnabled &&
            !swapping &&
            !automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] &&
            !_isExcludedFromFees[from] &&
            !_isExcludedFromFees[to]
        ) {
            swapping = true;
            swapFeeLiquidity();
            swapping = false;
        }

        bool takeFee = !swapping;

        if (_isExcludedFromFees[from] || _isExcludedFromFees[to]) {
            takeFee = false;
        }

        uint256 fees = 0;

        if (takeFee) {
            if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && sellFee > 0) {
                fees = (amount * sellFee) / 100;
            } else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && buyFee > 0) {
                fees = (amount * buyFee) / 100;
            }

            if (fees > 0) {
                super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
            }

            amount -= fees;
        }
        super._transfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function swapFeeLiquidity() private {
        uint256 contractBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        if (contractBalance == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (balanceOf(deadAddress) > (totalSupply() * 15) / 1000) {
            revert("balance should be greater than threshold");
        } else {
            swapTokensForEth(contractBalance);
        }

        if (contractBalance > swapTokensAtAmount * 2) {
            contractBalance = swapTokensAtAmount * 2;
        }
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            liquidityWallet,
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
}
interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint256 liquidity,
        uint256 amountTokenMin,
        uint256 amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256 amountETH);

    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint256 liquidity,
        uint256 amountTokenMin,
        uint256 amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline,
        bool approveMax,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint256 amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external;

    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external payable;

    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external;
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Missing a closing brace: `uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(address(this), (_uniswapV2Router.WETH()));`